# How to sign-off every git commit?

Tags: git

I know that I could do this:

```
$ git config --global alias.c 'commit -s'
```

... to sign-off all my commits.

But I would like to use `git commit`, since I am used to it.

Is there a way to make `git commit` sign-off my commits (without using the `-s` flag everytime)?

BTW, there is a setting in vscode:

[image: vscode-setting-signoff-git-commits]

Comment: I don't think you can alias the default command since you need to use it in the alias.

Comment: [_"**Note:** adding the `Signed-off-by` trailer to a patch should be a conscious act..."_](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-formatsignOff)

Comment: There is no such feature, by design, and there will not be. (It has been discussed in the past.) A sign-off on a commit has a particular meaning, and to sign off a commit must be a conscious decision. Therefore, you are required to type the `-s` every time. Make your own alias if you desire so, but that is not Git's business.

Comment: The setting in VS Code adds `-s` to all commit commands. It says so - _"Controls the signoff flag ..."_

Comment: @j6t In vscode it is possible. It has a setting for that. I added a screenshot.

Comment: Indeed. That is exactly what I mean by "make your own alias if you desire so."